# $_SESSION['id'] is null

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am trying to update the password in a php script,howerver $_SESSION['id'] is null. This is shown via the var_dump function. Hence I can't update it

```
<?php
session_start();
require "../init.php";
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    $password = $_POST['user_pass'];
    $passwordEncrypted = sha1($user_pass); 

    $confpassword = $_POST['confirm_pass'];
    $confPasswordEncrypted = sha1($confirmPass);  
    if($password !== $confpassword){
       echo "Passwords don't match!";
    }else{
        $select_query = "SELECT id FROM user_info";
        $run_select_query = mysqli_query($con,$select_query); 
        while ($row_post=mysqli_fetch_array($run_select_query)){

            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $user_id = $_SESSION['id'];
            var_dump($user_id);

        }

        $update_posts = "UPDATE user_info SET user_pass='$passwordEncrypted',confirm_pass ='$confPasswordEncrypted' WHERE id='$user_id'";  
        $run_update = mysqli_query($con,$update_posts); 
        echo "<script>alert('Post Has been Updated!')</script>";
    }

}
?>
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: `while ($row_post` then look at `$row['id']` ;-) wrong variable and error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php would have signaled that undefined variable.

Comment: Ooops. It took me so long for a simple typo! Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome Theo.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a wrong variable `$row` while assign value to `session` variable.

```
while ($row_post=mysqli_fetch_array($run_select_query)){
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row_post['id'];
    $user_id = $_SESSION['id'];
    var_dump($user_id);
}
```

Comment: yeah I said that too, 2 minutes prior to this

Comment: @Fred-ii-:  I am writing the answer while you commented on that :)

Comment: @Fred-ii- : any way I can delete the answer if you want, not greedy for repu :D

Comment: that's up to you, I'm not forcing your hand ;-)

Comment: let me enhance something to that answer so it will provide a bit more knowledge